# Adding value for the Primary key field in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key, user-input

I am working on a website with asp.net webforms with EF6, i have successfully generated model, now when i try to add the record to the database table, it doesn't work.

I have a table `Users` with field `Username` which i set as primary key, with no identity constraint. Now i have set the value for the `Username` from my code before calling `db.Users.Add` and `SaveChanges()`, however it does not detect the value in `Username` field and throws error saying

> the Username field could not be null.

How shall i insert value to the primary key field?

**Edits**

```
public class UsersDo : GenericDo
{
        [NotMapped]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int Username { get; set; }
 }
```

The reason i want to apply Primary key to the username is because, i have another table where i want to use username as a foreign key, but if i have any other field as primary key in Users table, it does not allow to keep username as foreign key in another table. i even tried composite primary key, even that does not help.

Comment: we need to see your classes and mappings

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a surrogate key here?  Perhaps you don't want to support editing of usernames, but why box in yourself without need?

Comment: you can use alternate key (surrogate key) for username. in this way, usernaem is not needed to be PK

Comment: could you please let me know how shall i create surrogate key and how that would allow me the refer in another table as foreign key using EF? Please note the username field won't be editable, it won't be auto-increemented too, the value for that will be accepted from user.

Comment: UserName is `int`, really?

Comment: Yes it will be 8 digit number

Comment: Ok. `int` key properties by default convention are treated as identity columns. Mark the UserName with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

Comment: I have made the Identity:false in the Migration script before updating database, hence my username field does not have any Identity constraint, but still it isn't accepting any values.

Comment: Have you considered the name `UserId` to avoid drastic confusion to future maintainers?  Pretty sure literally zero people would expect `UserName` to resolve to a number.

Comment: actually that 8 digit number field could be called `ITS` number, but since i am using asp.net membership i want to keep it named username for ease of login, would changing it to `ITS` work? because still i would have to keep `ITS` as primary key since i am referring it to another table. `UserId` is already mapped to `aspnet_Users` `UserId` which is `Guid`.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the migration script but the mapping. If you edit the migration script EF still thinks it's an identity column and doesn't provide a value on insert.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot @GertArnold, i updated the mapping, but i have another question, i made another update in script, wherein i updated the cascade: false and that took effect, then why the identity: false from script didn't took effect.